# Does wearing mail-only armor as a hunter give you any benefits?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Please feel free to change the question title, I wasn't sure how to ask.

I'm playing as a hunter and I just reached level 40, the thing is, I'm currently using leather heirloom armor which was originally created for rouges (at least I think so).

Now, with level 40, I would have the option to use mail armor, but since I don't have mail heirloom armor, I asked myself if its a good idea to continue using my leather armor or if I lose any benefits for not wearing a full mail set?

Comment: Please note that certain heirloom armor changes type at level 40. Strength mail turns into plate at 40, and certain leather turns into mail at 40. Cloth stays the same, as do weapons, trinkets, etc. that are not a specific armor type. The name normally gives a good indication, and [Wowpedia](http://wowpedia.org/) will tell you for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With level 40 you won't gain any benefits from it but at level 50 you will gain a skill called Mail Specialization that increases your agility by 5% if you have a full Mail Armor.

Apart from that the only real bonus is the extra armor. It's not nothing since you are a range character and you can sometimes even offtank stuff with your skill kit.

Also note that the armor bonuses are available to every class. Cloth classes will usually gain +5% int while Plate usually gains +5% strength (or int for pallys) etc. same applies to Leather and Mail.

Comment: So would you recommend to still use heirloom leather gear until level 80 (respectively level 85)?

Comment: @RandomDisplayName Well yes for Leveling the % bonus exp is really great and the 5% agi are not that important. But make sure you use Mail With max-level

Comment: @RandomDisplayName The XP benefits outweigh the missing armor and 5% agility whilst leveling. The reason the proficiency specializations were implemented were to discourage players from taking gear which didn't match their armor proficiency. For example, a restoration shaman taking intellect cloth over a holy/disc priest and intellect leather over a restoration druid, thus making it harder for priests to gear and very easy for shamans (druids were somewhere in-between).

Comment: @RandomDisplayName I would recommend getting the right heirlooms. The hunter/shaman Agility heirlooms automatically transform from leather to mail at level 40. If this is impractical, yeah, stick with the heirlooms you have; the XP bonus is way more important.